# Postgres find name table or

Tags: postgresql

[image]

how I can find if person is customer or supplier or employee with id_pers. 
I need query return name table or something relative .
I tried with this query :

```
 SELECT p.id_pers, p.name_pers 
,c.id_customer as customer
,e.id_emp as employee
,s.id_supplier as supplier
      from person p
 left join employee e  on p.id_pers=e.id_pers
 left join customer c  on p.id_pers=c.id_pers 
 left join supplier s  on p.id_pers=s.id_pers 
    where id_pers='12'
```

I don't' know how to get nature of person .

Comment: Could you share some sample data and the result you expect to get in return?

Comment: if person is customer result : customer ,                          if person is employee result : employee  ,                         if person is supplier result : supplier,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way to do it, but this should do it for you

```
SELECT id_pers,
   CASE WHEN id_pers IN (SELECT id_supplier FROM supplier) THEN 'supplier'
        WHEN id_pers IN (SELECT id_customer FROM customer) THEN 'customer'
        WHEN id_pers IN (SELECT id_emp FROM employee) THEN 'employee'
   END
FROM person
WHERE id_pers=12;


id_pers |   case
--------+----------
     12 | supplier
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Legato for the answer. It is very very  helpful :)  ,thank you again for your time and consideration.